Cannot access the service on k3s
I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm setting up my first project. The application responds with a hello world message on the '/' route. Here is my deployment file:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app
          image: my_app:0.1
          resources:
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000

And here is my service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30001

I execute the following command to get the node IP: kubectl get node -o wide and the output is:

karol-ms-7972   Ready    control-plane,master   18h   v1.30.4+k3s1
192.168.8.106           Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS   6.8.0-40-generic   containerd://1.7.20-k3s1

I type 192.168.8.106:30001 in my browser (also tried with curl) and nothing is there. When I execute curl localhost:8000 in the pod, I get the expected response, so the problem is with the Service, not the Pod.
I'll appreciate all the hints.
